# Any Way To get The selected Indices only in CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I want to get the selected Indices or Items only in checkBox lsit instead of iterating through each item as Like is there in ListBox.

I am Getting Selected Value In tWo case In this way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class ChkBxList_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string li = "";
        foreach(ListItem lt in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if(lt.Selected)
            li += lt.Text;

        }
        Response.Write(li);


    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string li = "";
        foreach (int lt in ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices())
        {
          li += ListBox1.Items[lt].Text;

        }
        Response.Write(li);


    }
}
```

In ListBox we have the Option To get Seected Only Items is there any For Check Box List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually answered your own question.  There is no way to get the selected only items in the `CheckBoxList` control, unlike the `ListBox` control.

This article has an explanation and a work around help method.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/02/426346.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is but you could use this extension method that does exactly that:

```
public List<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this CheckBoxList checkBoxList)
{
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach(ListItem lt in checkBoxList)
    {
        if(lt.Selected)
            list.Add(lt);
    }
    return list;
}


//Call it like this
checkBoxList.GetSelectedItems();
```